# kotlin grpc.StreamObserver to deletate to rx.PublishSubject

Tags: java, rx-java, kotlin, delegation, grpc

When using GRPC whenever we declare streaming api

```
rpc heartBeat(Empty) returns (stream ServiceStatus){}
```

we have googles simple interface for observer pattern `StreamObserver` (this is what protobuf will generate for us)

```
public interface StreamObserver<V> {
  void onNext(V var1);

  void onError(Throwable var1);

  void onCompleted();
}
```

Now what you want to do is to convert this to an actual `Observable` and only after that pass it for further use.

```
override fun heartBeat(arg: Empty): Observable<ServiceStatus> {
    // we create rx java subject
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<ServiceStatus>()

    // we create grpc observer and delegate all calls to rx java
    val observer = object : StreamObserver<ServiceStatus> {

        override fun onNext(value: ServiceStatus) {
            subject.onNext(value)
        }

        override fun onError(error: Throwable) {
            subject.onError(error)
        }

        override fun onCompleted() {
            subject.onCompleted()
        }
    }

    // we use grpc observer for generated api
    asyncStub.heartBeat(arg, observer)

    // but we pass rx observable (subject) to client code
    return subject
}
```

now I'm new to Kotlin but i cant figure out with existing delegation functionalities **is there a way to make Subject delegate of StreamObserver?** 
**Is there a more expressive way to write this piece of code in Kotlin?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create a generic method that creates a `StreamObserver`, passes it to its lambda argument and wraps the result in `Observable`.

```
inline fun <T> asObservable(
    crossinline body: (StreamObserver<T>) -> Unit): Observable<T> {
  return Observable.create { subscription ->
    val observer = object : StreamObserver<T> {
      override fun onNext(value: T) {
        subscription.onNext(value)
      }

      override fun onError(error: Throwable) {
        subscription.onError(error)
      }

      override fun onCompleted() {
        subscription.onCompleted()
      }
    }
    body(observer)
  }
}
```

Then you can implement RPC methods in the following way.

```
override fun heartBeat(arg: Empty): Observable<ServiceStatus> =
    asObservable { asyncStub.heartBeat(arg, it) }
```

Comment: I've created an extension function so that you could call publishSubject.asGrpcObserver(), but i didn't think about solution like this, got to try it...

Comment: Why I asked this is because we can see clear delegation task here, and i could not figure out how to delegate with kotlins delegation features, so i suppose this situation is not applicable for delegation?

Comment: Delegation will not work here because despite of `StreamObserver` and `Observable` having similar methods their types a different. And you can delegate invocations only to instance of the same type. And I wouldn't recommend you to use a `Subject` here as an `Observable` works well here.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about crossinline :)